# Construct window with list of keybindings for the Emacs Debugger

Tags: key-bindings, window, debugging

I always forget the keybindings for the Emacs debugger. I'd like to have a small window open at the same time the debugger window opens with a list of keybindings (I'm thinking of something that would appear similar to the bottom Ediff window in this screenshot https://gpvprasad.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/ediff.png).

I was hoping a package like guide-key could perform this task but it doesn't seem possible.

What is the simplest way to make a window appear containing a concise list of keybindings for the active window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`C-h m`** (command `describe-mode`) is your friend, always. Including in Debugger mode.

**`C-h b`** (command `describe-bindings`) lists more bindings.

---

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can get the possible keys at any time, anywhere, and you can complete prefix keys.  This is [**key completion**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).

The relevant command is **`icicle-complete-keys`**.  By default, **Icicles** binds it to **`S-TAB`** in places where `S-TAB` is not already bound.

`S-TAB` is already bound to command `backward-button` in Debugger mode (that is, in `debugger-mode-map`).  You can bind `icicle-complete-keys` to another key in that map, or bind it to `S-TAB` there, if you like.

Comment: It seems like this is the correct answer. Icicles is a little heavyweight to use only for this purpose (though I have used it in the past with success). I'll probably stick with just using `h` to describe the mode.